# Wikidata SPARQL Query for details on a person produces duplicate results for their altNames

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I am building a [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FitemLabel%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28%3FaltNames%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%22%3B%22%29%20AS%20%3Faliases%29%20%3FitemDesc%20%3FgenderLabel%20%3Fbirthday%20%3FplaceOfBirthLabel%20%3Fimage%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fed%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%22%7C%22%29%20AS%20%3Fedus%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fitem%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ5284%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ28920824%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ93592590%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ109596276%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3FaltNames.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3FaltNames%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP21%20%3Fgender.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fbirthday.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP19%20%3FplaceOfBirth.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP69%20%3Fstatement.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20%28ps%3AP69%2Frdfs%3Alabel%29%20%3FeduLabel.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3FeduLabel%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP580%20%3FedStart.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FedEnd.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20%28pq%3AP512%2Frdfs%3Alabel%29%20%3FedDegrees.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3FedDegrees%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20%28pq%3AP812%2Frdfs%3Alabel%29%20%3FedMajors.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3FedMajors%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FedStart%29%2C%20CONCAT%28%22%3A%3Astart%3A%22%2C%20STR%28YEAR%28%3FedStart%29%29%29%2C%20%22%22%29%20AS%20%3FedStartText%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FedEnd%29%2C%20CONCAT%28%22%3A%3Aend%3A%22%2C%20STR%28YEAR%28%3FedEnd%29%29%29%2C%20%22%22%29%20AS%20%3FedEndText%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FedDegrees%29%2C%20CONCAT%28%22%3A%3Adegrees%3A%22%2C%20STR%28%3FedDegrees%29%29%2C%20%22%22%29%20AS%20%3FedDegreeText%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FedMajors%29%2C%20CONCAT%28%22%3A%3Amajors%3A%22%2C%20STR%28%3FedMajors%29%29%2C%20%22%22%29%20AS%20%3FedMajorText%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28CONCAT%28%3FeduLabel%2C%20%3FedStartText%2C%20%3FedEndText%2C%20%3FedDegreeText%2C%20%3FedMajorText%29%20AS%20%3Fed%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20schema%3Adescription%20%3FitemDesc.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDesc%20%3FgenderLabel%20%3Fbirthday%20%3Fimage%20%3FplaceOfBirthLabel) to return specific information about specified individuals on Wikidata. There are a few things that I am not happy about, but my primary question is why does this return as many duplicate lists of aliases as there are academic institutions in their educatedAt (P69) statements?

For example, Bill Gates is listed as going to 3 educational institutions, and so his aliases are repeated 3 times?  How are these things tied together in my query?

Query:

```
SELECT ?itemLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(?altNames; SEPARATOR = ";") AS ?aliases) ?itemDesc ?genderLabel ?birthday ?placeOfBirthLabel ?image (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?ed; SEPARATOR = "|") AS ?edus) WHERE {
  VALUES ?item {
    wd:Q5284
    wd:Q28920824
    wd:Q93592590
    wd:Q109596276
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item skos:altLabel ?altNames.
    FILTER((LANG(?altNames)) = "en")
  }
  {
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P21 ?gender. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?birthday. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P19 ?placeOfBirth. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?image. }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  }
  {
    OPTIONAL {
      ?item p:P69 ?statement.
      ?statement (ps:P69/rdfs:label) ?eduLabel.
      FILTER((LANG(?eduLabel)) = "en")
      OPTIONAL { ?statement pq:P580 ?edStart. }
      OPTIONAL { ?statement pq:P582 ?edEnd. }
      OPTIONAL {
        ?statement (pq:P512/rdfs:label) ?edDegrees.
        FILTER((LANG(?edDegrees)) = "en")
      }
      OPTIONAL {
        ?statement (pq:P812/rdfs:label) ?edMajors.
        FILTER((LANG(?edMajors)) = "en")
      }
      BIND(IF(BOUND(?edStart), CONCAT("::start:", STR(YEAR(?edStart))), "") AS ?edStartText)
      BIND(IF(BOUND(?edEnd), CONCAT("::end:", STR(YEAR(?edEnd))), "") AS ?edEndText)
      BIND(IF(BOUND(?edDegrees), CONCAT("::degrees:", STR(?edDegrees)), "") AS ?edDegreeText)
      BIND(IF(BOUND(?edMajors), CONCAT("::majors:", STR(?edMajors)), "") AS ?edMajorText)
      BIND(CONCAT(?eduLabel, ?edStartText, ?edEndText, ?edDegreeText, ?edMajorText) AS ?ed)
    }
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?item schema:description ?itemDesc.
  }
}
GROUP BY ?itemLabel ?itemDesc ?genderLabel ?birthday ?image ?placeOfBirthLabel
```

Result:

[image: Table showing query results]

Comment: There are two other concerns I have - which are secondary and I may make new questions for them:
1) How should I handle the cases of multiple major or degree qualifiers, I am pretty sure this is just bringing in one of them even if there are multiple.
2) I know this has been asked and answered multiple times but if I use this query to return JSON using the "modern javascript" method for example, how could I make it so that the EducatedAt entries and their qualifiers are nested in that JSON, rather than using these clunky and potentially buggy separators?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a DISTINCT flag to the GROUP_CONCAT function.

```
SELECT ?itemLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?altNames; SEPARATOR = ";") AS ?aliases) ?itemDesc ?genderLabel ?birthday ?placeOfBirthLabel ?image (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?ed; SEPARATOR = "|") AS ?edus)
```

[Working example](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FitemLabel%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FaltNames%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%22%3B%22%29%20AS%20%3Faliases%29%20%3FitemDesc%20%3FgenderLabel%20%3Fbirthday%20%3FplaceOfBirthLabel%20%3Fimage%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fed%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%22%7C%22%29%20AS%20%3Fedus%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fitem%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ5284%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ28920824%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ93592590%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ109596276%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3FaltNames.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3FaltNames%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP21%20%3Fgender.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fbirthday.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP19%20%3FplaceOfBirth.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP69%20%3Fstatement.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20%28ps%3AP69%2Frdfs%3Alabel%29%20%3FeduLabel.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3FeduLabel%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP580%20%3FedStart.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FedEnd.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20%28pq%3AP512%2Frdfs%3Alabel%29%20%3FedDegrees.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3FedDegrees%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20%28pq%3AP812%2Frdfs%3Alabel%29%20%3FedMajors.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3FedMajors%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FedStart%29%2C%20CONCAT%28%22%3A%3Astart%3A%22%2C%20STR%28YEAR%28%3FedStart%29%29%29%2C%20%22%22%29%20AS%20%3FedStartText%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FedEnd%29%2C%20CONCAT%28%22%3A%3Aend%3A%22%2C%20STR%28YEAR%28%3FedEnd%29%29%29%2C%20%22%22%29%20AS%20%3FedEndText%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FedDegrees%29%2C%20CONCAT%28%22%3A%3Adegrees%3A%22%2C%20STR%28%3FedDegrees%29%29%2C%20%22%22%29%20AS%20%3FedDegreeText%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28IF%28BOUND%28%3FedMajors%29%2C%20CONCAT%28%22%3A%3Amajors%3A%22%2C%20STR%28%3FedMajors%29%29%2C%20%22%22%29%20AS%20%3FedMajorText%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28CONCAT%28%3FeduLabel%2C%20%3FedStartText%2C%20%3FedEndText%2C%20%3FedDegreeText%2C%20%3FedMajorText%29%20AS%20%3Fed%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20schema%3Adescription%20%3FitemDesc.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDesc%20%3FgenderLabel%20%3Fbirthday%20%3Fimage%20%3FplaceOfBirthLabel)